# applying the Particle swarm optimization algorithm into multi-dimentional searching space?

Tags: python, optimization, particle-swarm

Can anyone help me to understand how to apply the PSO algorithm (Particle swarm optimization) for the optimization problem of a function in an N-dimensional searching space, for example, I have a function that has 7 parameters each varying in its proper interval [min, max] with a different 
step to advance in every interval!

Comment: This is unclear: By default, when nothing else is stated, PSO operates on functions ℝⁿ → ℝ for general *n*; see [e.g. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization#Algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from reading the algorithm of PSO, it is already equipped to handle a function in multiple-dimensional space because it operates on a N-dim vector.

You can equate each parameter that you are optimizing to be a different dimension in your vector, and consider your function (f) to take a 7-dim vector instead of 7 parameters.

The algorithm on Wikipedia is as follows:

```
Let S be the number of particles in the swarm, each having a position xi ∈ ℝn in the search-space and a velocity vi ∈ ℝn.
Let pi be the best known position of particle i and let g be the best known position of the entire swarm. A basic PSO algorithm is then:[10]

for each particle i = 1, ..., S do
   Initialize the particle's position with a uniformly distributed random vector: x_i ~ U(b_lo, b_up)
   Initialize the particle's best known position to its initial position: p_i ← x_i
   if f(p_i) < f(g) then
       update the swarm's best known  position: g ← p_i
   Initialize the particle's velocity: vi ~ U(-|b_up-b_lo|, |b_up-b_lo|)
while a termination criterion is not met do:
   for each particle i = 1, ..., S do
      """for each dimension d = 1, ..., n do"""
         Pick random numbers: r_p, r_g ~ U(0,1)
         Update the particle's velocity: v_(i,d) ← ω v_(i,d) + φ_p r_p (p_(i,d)-x_(i,d)) + φ_g r_g (g_d-x_(i,d))
      Update the particle's position: x_i ← x_i + v_i
      if f(x_i) < f(p_i) then
         Update the particle's best known position: p_i ← x_i
         if f(p_i) < f(g) then
            Update the swarm's best known position: g ← p_i

The values b_lo and b_up represents the lower and upper boundaries of the search-space. 
The termination criterion can be the number of iterations performed, or a solution where the adequate objective function value is found.[11] 
The parameters ω, φ_p, and φ_g are selected by the practitioner and control the behaviour and efficacy of the PSO method, see below...
```

As you can see in the triple quotes, for every particle, it will update every single dimension (ie each one of your parameters) so you do not have to worry about having N-dimensions.

You can also write your 7 lower boundaries as a vector b_lo and your 7 upper boundaries as another vector b_up. It also seems that your boundaries that you are worrying about only have an effect on the initial iteration of the loops, where b_lo and b_up are used.

---

--update to question by OP--

So, the interval seems to only matter with `b_lo` and `b_up`. So in your case, b_lo would look something like `[7, 30, ...]` and b_up would look something like `[13, 90, ...]`.

For the step sizes, happens here

```
Update the particle's velocity: v_(i,d) ← ω v_(i,d) + φ_p r_p (p_(i,d)-x_(i,d)) + φ_g r_g (g_d-x_(i,d))
      Update the particle's position: x_i ← x_i + v_i
```

If you want the step in each dimension to stay constant, you will have to add a conditional to the position update. I do not recommend this happening, because then it would probably take longer to optimize and you lose some of the advantages of this optimization.

So first the conditional:

```
if v_(i,d) < 0:
    Update the particle's position x_i ← x_i - (step_size for that dimension)
elif v_(i,d) > 0:
    Update the particle's position x_i ← x_i + (step_size for that dimension)
else v_(i,d) is 0:
    # You can either do one of the above updates or pass and not move the particle in this dimension
```

You can also definitely simplify updating the velocity, but I would recommend just sticking to the velocity given by the formula.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Regarding the step to advance in each interval, for example for the first parameter "a" the interval is [7,13] and the step is 1 and the 2nd parameter "b" is [30,90 ] and the step is 5, etc. Which part of the code should be changed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to change code, you just need to change the interval for each parameter. For example, we have 5 parameters to be optimized, we just need to define the whole search space with two array - upper bound and lower bound like this: lb: [7,30,15,25,30], ub: [13,90,20,30,45].